# Including associations optimization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord, associations

I'm looking for help with Ruby optimization regarding loading of associations on demand.

This is simplified example. I have 3 models: `Post`, `Comment`, `User`. References are: `Post` has many comments and `Comment` has reference to `User` (:author). Now when I go to the post page, I expect to see post body + all comments (and their respective authors names). This requires following 2 queries:

```
select * from Post -- to get post data (1 row)
select * from Comment inner join User -- to get comment + usernames (N rows)
```

In the code I have:

```
Post.find(params[:id], :include => { :comments => [:author] }
```

But it doesn't work as expected: as I see in the back end, there're still N+1 hits (some of them are cached though). How can I optimize that?

**UPD**
After some investigation, it looks like code was correct, but it doesn't work as expected in case I have named belongs_to in a Comment model. Once I changed from :author to :user, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with 2/3 queries, you can try:

```
@post = Post.find params[:id]
@comments = Comments.find_by_post_id(params[:id], :include => [:author])
```

or

```
@comments = @post.comments(:include => [:author])
```

Edit: Have you tried with:

Post.find(params[:id], :include => { :comments => :author }

Comment: I did right by the last variant, and still see that it loads authors separately (hitting database more than once, by the # of comments).

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#nested-associations-hash, it looks like you can nest includes

Comment: @Corey - yes, I was following this article as you can see in my questions, but that did't work as expected.

Comment: @vlad - did u investigate how one can order comments by create date desc?

Comment: @post.comments(:include => [:author], :order => 'created_at DESC')

Answer (score 1):

In my project I have a similar relationship to your `Post`, `Comment`, and `User` models.  I only see three actual sql queries.

```
Post.find(1, :include => { :comments => [:author] })
```

From the debug log it shows these three queries

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.`id` = 1)
SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE (`comments`.`post_id` = 1)
SELECT * FROM `authors` WHERE (`authors`.`id` IN (4,8,15,16,23,42))
```

Comment: I updated, it changes the way it pulls users (authors) depending on what I have in belongs_to.

Comment: Did u investigate how one can order comments by create date desc?

Comment: so you mean this?: Post.find(1, :include => {:comments => :author}, :order => 'comments.created_at desc')

Comment: Not exactly: it translates this query as inner join instead of additional query and doesn't include author to comments.